# char[] to String sequence mismatching in Java for Unicode characters

Tags: java, android, string, unicode, char

I have a method like below (please ignore the code optimization issue.) This method replaces the Unicode character (Bengali characters)

```
static String swap(String temp, char c) 
{
    Integer length=temp.length();
    char[] charArray = temp.toCharArray();
      for(int u=0;u<length;u++)
        {           
            if(charArray[u]==c)
            {
                    char g=charArray[u];
                    charArray[u]=charArray[u-1];
                    charArray[u-1]=g;
            }                   
        }
    String string2 = new String(charArray);
    return string2;
}
```

while debugging, i got the values of charArray like the below image:
[image]

please note that the characters are in a sequenced format what I want. 
 But after the execution of the statement, the value stored in String variable is mismatched. like below:
[image]

***I want to display the string as "রেরেরে" but it is displaying "েরেরের" what i not want. Please tell me what I am doing wrong.***

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note - I don't know Bengali, but I know a bit (or a lot, depending on whom you ask) about Unicode and how Java supports it. The answer assumes knowledge of the latter and not the former.

Going by the [Unicode 6.0 Bengali chart](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0980.pdf), `রে` is a combination of the dependent vowel sign `ে` (0x09C7) and the consonant `র` (0x09B0) and is represented as a sequence of two characters in the character array.

If you are getting the dependent vowel sign alone, in the resulting character sequence (and hence the string), then your optimization is likely to be kooky, as it appears to assume that Bengali characters in Unicode can be represented as a single Unicode codepoint or a single `char` variable in Java; this would result in the scenario where a consonant would be replaced by another consonant, but the dependent vowel preceding the consonant would never be replaced.

I think a correct optimization must therefore consider the presence of dependent vowels, and compare the following consonant in addition to the vowel , i.e. it must compare two characters in the character array, instead of comparing individual characters. This might also imply that your method signature must be changed to allow for a `char[]` to be passed, instead of a single `char`, so that Bengali characters can be replaced with the intended Bengali character, instead of replacing a Unicode codepoint with another, which is what is being done currently.

The notes in other answers on the `ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException` is valid. The following example that uses your character replacement algorithm demonstrates that not only is your algorithm incorrect, but it is quite possible for the exception to be thrown:

```
class CodepointReplacer
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String str1 = "রেরেরে";
            /* 
             * The following is a linguistically invalid sequence,
             * but Java does not concern itself with linguistical correctness
             * if the String or char sequence has been constructed incorrectly.
             */
        String str2 = "েরেরের"; 
            /*
             * replacement character র for our strings
             * It is not রে as one would anticipate.
             */ 
        char c = str1.charAt(1);

        optimizeKookily(str1, c);
        optimizeKookily(str2, c);
    }

    private static void optimizeKookily(String temp, char c)
    {
        Integer length = temp.length();
        char[] charArray = temp.toCharArray();
        for (int u = 0; u < length; u++)
        {
            if (charArray[u] == c)
            {
                char g = charArray[u];
                charArray[u] = charArray[u - 1]; //throws exception on second invocation of this method.
                charArray[u - 1] = g;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A better character replacement strategy would therefore be to use the `String.replace` (the `CharSequence` variant) or `String.replaceAll` functions, assuming that you would know how to use these with Bengali characters.

Comment: Hi.Thanks. but it didn't worked. Error: "Some character can not be mapped using 'Cp1252' character encoding." Actually we produce the below unicode sequence from our web service in XML format. "String s="\u09B0\u09C7\u09B0\u09C7\u09B0\u09C7";" it represents "রেরেরে" in Bangla fonts in MS Word or notepad. But since Android doesn't support phonetic Bangla representation, it displayed incorrect. So, we wanted to replace the characters. For a single replacement, it worked good. But for multiple replacement in a word, it is not working.We are using http://macchiato.com/unicode/convert.html

Comment: I didn't post any solution in code, so I don't know what you mean by "but it didn't worked". If you are attempting to run my posted code, then you need to save the code as UTF-8 or UTF-16 and not in Windows cp1252 which does not understand the Bangla literals. Secondly, I hope you are aware of what a `char` in Java is, as far as Unicode support is concerned. If you haven't realized that a `char` is not the same as a single alphabet in a language, then I would suggest reading up on [Unicode](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html), and also learn to read the Unicode Bengali chart.

Comment: Secondly, if you need to understand why your replacement is failing, take a look at the underlying byte array of your String. If you put a watch on `temp.getBytes()` in Eclipse, you'll realize that your code is not replacing the characters correctly. And if you have to fix that, you need to understand how substitution of characters ought to be done in Unicode.

Comment: By the way, what are you replacing the sequence `\u09B0\u09C7\u09B0\u09C7\u09B0\u09C7` with? I can attempt posting a solution, for that specific requirement, but if you need to understand how it works, then you'll need to understand how the 3 Bangla characters map to 6 characters in Java, and why replacing 1 Java character is a bad idea.

Comment: I am trying to interchange the "\u09B0\u09C7" to "\u09C7\u09B0" so that it will return instead of "র ে" to "রে"

Comment: I don't understand - why do you want to convert from a valid sequence `\u09B0\u09C7` to an invalid one `\u09C7\u09B0`? `রেরেরে` (which is a sequence of bytes `[9, -80, 9, -57, 9, -80, 9, -57, 9, -80, 9, -57]` will then become `েরেরের` or `[9, -57, 9, -80, 9, -57, 9, -80, 9, -57, 9, -80]`, which is the current problem. Did not occur to you that a sequence of invalid bytes will be displayed in a best effort attempt to display valid Bengali characters resulting in this scenario?

Comment: Also, if you didn't understand the previous comment, take a look at [this character inspector application](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/09/java-character-inspector-application.html) written by [McDowell](http://stackoverflow.com/users/304/mcdowell); you can paste the Strings `রেরেরে` and `েরেরের` and see the Unicode codepoint representations. By replacing `\u09B0\u09C7` with `\u09C7\u09B0`, you really haven't achieved anything useful.

Comment: I really appreciate your time. Thanks. But unfortunately, Android is not capable to display the bangla text the way we write in Notepad or Word. Until Android has the solution of this problem, we must change this sequence. There is no other way.

Comment: I don't think you've understood anything here. Your current code has changed the sequence to what you desire, except that it is invalid and makes no sense to any application including an Android app. Changing sequences around is not going to change anything as long as the individual characters continue to be Bengali. Any renderer will continue to interpret the characters as Bengali.

Comment: +1 - once again a fine demonstration why the notion of "character" is far more high-level than general purpose programming languages handle at the type level. A dedicated unicode text processing library is definitely called for here.

Answer (score 0):

problem is in

```
    for(int u=0;u<length;u++)
            {           
                if(charArray[u]==c)
                {
                        char g=charArray[u];
                        charArray[u]=charArray[u-1];
                        charArray[u-1]=g;
                }                   
            }
See when u=0 what is the value of charArray[u-1] that is the index -1.Modify your for loop or just put the condition where u=0.
```

Comment: You are missing the point. I am displaying the scenario in the images. If there is any problem as you mentioned, it would throw IndexOutOfBound Exception or something like this. Am I right?

Comment: Well, may be its better to know how you want to modify your charArray to get the new string

Comment: Again,its not a good practice leaving such error without handling

Comment: I have mentioned what I want in the last. So, i have no problem whatever way it can make it happen. Please give some suggestions perhaps.

Comment: you want to display your desired sequence from string2?

Comment: the sequence is ok at the charArray variable if you check.But the problem is when I make a string from that chars. yes. I want to display the string2 but in the charArray sequence. this is the problem I am facing. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Your code will cause an IndexOutOfBound Exception.
When u=0, charArray[u-1]=-1.